# How to index CMS content for searching

Tags: asp.net, search, content-management-system, indexing

I want to provide a search mechanism on my CMS.  What is the preferred approach, what would be the best indexing technology to allow a site-wide search?

The CMS is written in .Net.

Comment: Does you cms use a persistance layer with entities? What DB are you running it on?

Comment: Yes, it runs against Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you have a look at [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for .NET. Its a very nice helper when it comes to searching and its easy to use.

A very smooth feature with Lucene is that you can set annotations on your entities. This makes it very easy to customize how different variables should be indexed and searched for. (I have only used Lucene with Java, might be some differences with .NET)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Site Search for this, the paid version is something like $100(so thats what? 20 euros?) a year. You can customise the search result as much as you want, you call GSS with there api and get the results in XML. There is also an autocomplete included. Allot of Google search features are supported.